# Specify a chosen default version of conda package through conda-forge / conda-install

Tags: continuous-integration, conda, conda-build, conda-forge

I'd like to distribute multiple versions of a package through conda. Specifically, I'd like to do something like this:

```
...
package-v1.2-dev
package-v1.2
package-v1.1-dev
package-v1.1
package-v1.0
```

The trick is that I'd like to have the "latest" or default package be the release versions that do not have `-dev`. As I understand it, `conda install <package>` without a version number will install the newest build. In my case, that will always be `-dev`. Is it possible to make the default a specific version number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by specifying a custom "label" for your `dev` packages.  Keep using the default `main` label for your release packages, but use a non-main label (e.g. `dev`) for the other packages.

First, a quick note about version numbers: conda package versions [must not contain the `-` character](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html), so `v1.2-dev` is not a valid version.  For the following examples, I'll use `v1.2.dev`.

---

Here's how to upload your packages:

```bash
anaconda upload mypackage-v1.2.tar.bz2
anaconda upload --label dev mypackage-v1.2.dev.tar.bz2
```

(You can also manipulate the labels for existing packages via your account on the http://anaconda.org website.)

By default, your users will only download your main packages. Users who want the `dev` packages will have two choices:

1. They can specify the `dev` label on the command-line:

   ```
   conda install -c mychannel/label/dev mypackage
   ```

OR

2. They can add your `dev` label to their `.condarc` config

   ```yaml
   # .condarc
   channels:
     - mychannel/label/dev # dev label
     - mychannel           # main label only
     - conda-forge
     - defaults
   ```

   And then there's no need to specify the channel on the command-line:

   ```bash
   conda install mypackage
   ```

---

PS -- Here's a side note about something you wrote above:

> As I understand it, `conda install <package>` without a version number will install the newest build

Just to clarify, it doesn't install the "newest" in chronological sense, but rather the highest compatible version according to [conda's `VersionOrder` logic](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/7132ac7a713a6d61d5da317d98cea961af748d75/conda/models/version.py#L47). That logic is designed to be largely compatible with relevant Python conventions (e.g. [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) and others), but with some affordances for compatibility with other languages' conventions, too.

**Please note:** As far as conda (and PEP440) is concerned, `1.2.dev` comes BEFORE `1.2`.  (Maybe you already knew that, but I don't consider it obvious.)

```py
$ python
>>> from conda.models.version import VersionOrder
>>> VersionOrder('1.2.dev') < VersionOrder('1.2')
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information on the version ordering. Apparently, I've been versioning my projects all wrong! I consider `v1.2.dev` to be the dev branch after `v1.2` is tagged and released. It sounds like the Python convention is that `v1.2.dev` is after `v1.1` is released and is `v1.2` in development.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not obvious, IMHO.  Surprised me the first time I saw it. [PEP440 assigns special meanings to some identifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#public-version-identifiers):  `[N!]N(.N)*[{a|b|rc}N][.postN][.devN]`

Comment: FYI to integrate with Conda-forge: https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#installing-a-pre-release-build

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that feature.  Thanks!